# limit n results per group by - Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am trying to create a query where I can pull the last 3 forum posts per category that is shown on the screen. Here is the way my model is setup:

```
class ForumCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class)


class ForumPost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ForumCategory)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My current query returns the 3 most recent posts in general and not 3 per category:

```
categories = ForumCategory.objects.filter(class_id=class_id)
        forum_post = ForumPost.objects.filter(category_id__in=categories.values_list('id', flat=True)).order_by('-category_id')[:3]
```

So I first grab all categories that belong to a specific class and I want to list those categories along with the 3 most recent posts in each category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @exprator said but a small change,

```
categories = ForumCategory.objects.filter(class_id=class_id)
result_dict = {}
for cat in categories:
    forum_post = ForumPost.objects.filter(category__pk=cat.pk).order_by('-created')[:3]
    result_dict[cat.name] = forum_post
```

Then the queryset for each category can be accessed from the corresponding category name.

Answer (score 4):

You have no resort but to use raw SQL in this case. If you're using PostgreSQL something like this is needed:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY forum_category_id)  
FROM forum_post) x WHERE x.row_number <= 3;
```

Unfortunately, you can't express this in Django ORM for now due to this ticket: [Provide a way to manage grouping with RawSQL](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26602)

Comment: I thought that question of the author assumed fetching all the data using exactly one SQL request. Otherwise, the task is trivial. You can iterate over categories, but that is obvious solution and it generates too many queries (not a problem for small application/site, big problem when you have a highload project).